# PHP- Short code to clear screen if certain parameter passed?

Tags: php, html

Lets say I have a simple php index website page.

I have a need to clear the screen depending on when certain parameters are passed to the index page. The code that checks the passed parameters could appear anywhere in the index page.

If the parameter is not passed the page loads normally, if it is passed it clears/blanks the screen or alternatively pops a blank window to echo into.

I want to do it as efficiently as possible as a one-liner leading to my echo statement (if possible).

Comment: See question for question

Comment: @user1166981 I don't think you get it.

Comment: Why do you need to "clear/blank" the screen or "pop a blank window"?

Comment: Because that is the functionality I want to achieve on this page so I can echo something else from a blank page.

Comment: You do not specify what you are actually having trouble with. Are you having trouble getting the parameter?

Comment: I don't know the best way to stop the page loading and for it to be cleared (as a blank canvas) so I can echo something else into it. Say index.php?param=test, I have a $_get of a param test (anywhere in the page loading process) if param test is passed, the page stops loading (from wherever it is up to, clears/blanks, and something else is echo'd.

Comment: If during your script execution you have already written something using echo and you want to cancel that use this function : `ob_end_clean()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you simply reference a tag in javascript to

```
<body></body>
```

and then set the innerhtml value from there?

For example, we can use a button that will use the

```
document.body.innerHTML
```

property to set the page to whatever we want like such . . .

```
document.body.innerHTML = 'cleared';
```

or . . .

```
<button name="btnClear" id="btnClearMe" onclick="document.body.innerHTML = 'cleared'" >Clear Page</button>
```

full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body id="bdContent">
    <button name="btnClear" id="btnClearMe" onclick="document.body.innerHTML = 'cleared'" >Clear Page</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show me an example of what you mean please?

Comment: Ok the example and full code is posted.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you want to either have your php echo nothing, or echo the page, depending on some variable.  If this is what you want, you can just put this at the top of your php

```
<?php
    if(condition){return;}
    //the rest of you page goes here

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if($_GET['parameter'] == 'blank'){
  echo '';
}else{
  echo 'something';
}
?>
```

- mysite.com (this will show something)
- mysite.com?parameter=blank (this will show nothing)

Comment: Thank you for replying with an answer. However the $_GET check could be done from anywhere in the php page, not necessarily at the start. Can this be modified to fit with that requirement?

Comment: ? just put it at the start